# Is "for( int k = 5; k--;)" faster than "for( int k = 4; k > -1; --k)"

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

The question says it all: Is

```
for( int k = 5; k--;)
```

faster than

```
for( int k = 4; k > -1; --k)
```

and why?

**EDIT:**
I generated the assembly for debug and release in MSVC2012. But (it's my first time analyzing assembly code), I can't really make sense out of it. I alredy added the "std::cout" to prevent the compiler from removing both loops during release optimization.
Can someone help me what the assembly means?

**Debug:**

```
; 10   :    for( int k = 5; k--;){ std::cout << k; }

    mov DWORD PTR _k$2[ebp], 5
$LN5@wmain:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$2[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR tv65[ebp], eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _k$2[ebp]
    sub ecx, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _k$2[ebp], ecx
    cmp DWORD PTR tv65[ebp], 0
    je  SHORT $LN4@wmain
    mov esi, esp
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$2[ebp]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z
    cmp esi, esp
    call    __RTC_CheckEsp
    jmp SHORT $LN5@wmain
$LN4@wmain:

; 11   : 
; 12   :    for( int k = 4; k > -1; --k){ std::cout << k; }

    mov DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp], 4
    jmp SHORT $LN3@wmain
$LN2@wmain:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp]
    sub eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp], eax
$LN3@wmain:
    cmp DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp], -1
    jle SHORT $LN6@wmain
    mov esi, esp
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp]
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z
    cmp esi, esp
    call    __RTC_CheckEsp
    jmp SHORT $LN2@wmain
$LN6@wmain:
```

**Release:**

```
; 10   :    for( int k = 5; k--;){ std::cout << k; }

    mov esi, 5
$LL5@wmain:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    dec esi
    push    esi
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z
    test    esi, esi
    jne SHORT $LL5@wmain

; 11   : 
; 12   :    for( int k = 4; k > -1; --k){ std::cout << k; }

    mov esi, 4
    npad    3
$LL3@wmain:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    push    esi
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z
    dec esi
    cmp esi, -1
    jg  SHORT $LL3@wmain
```

Comment: Which compiler and CPU architecture are you using/targeting?

Comment: Why not write a test and time it?  The results are likely to be academic anyway as a fast loop on its own is pretty useless; most likely whatever action is taking place inside the loop will dominate the timing.

Comment: What is preventing you from testing this yourself?

Comment: To me, they should be equal. Both need an comparison instruction, decrements instruction etc.

Comment: The answer is indeterminable as it will depend on a lot of things, but I would be surprised if they were not identical on any modern compiler performing an optimised build.

Comment: Simplest way to find out is by checking the disassembly of each option. There's a good chance that they will be identical.

Comment: This question is quite meaningless. As well as a dependence on target architecture and compiler, the body of the loop will be important. Perhaps unrolling is faster still.

Comment: There might be a difference because modern compilers should optimize `k++` to `++k` in the second example. Therefore, the latter will likely have one more `move` operation.

Comment: @the_mandrill sure, the loop content dominates, but in code with lots of long but small-content loops, this may make a difference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Honestly, what prevents me is lack of experience with assemblies (see edit in the question)

Answer (score 6):

[ *UPDATE* question has been updated so this is no longer different ] <strike>They do different things... the first one executes the loop for `k` values 4 down to 0, while the second one loops from 5 down to 1... if say the loop body does work related to the magnitude of the number, then they might differ in performance.</strike>

Ignoring that, on most CPUs `k--` incidentally sets the "flags" register commonly called the "zero" flag, so no further explicit comparison is needed before deciding whether to exit.  Still, ***an optimiser should realise that and avoid any unnecessary second comparison even with the second loop***.

Generic quip: compilers are allowed to do lots of things, and the Standard certainly doesn't say anything about the relative performance of these two implementations, so ultimately the only way to know - if you have reason to care - is to use the same compiler and command line options you want for production then inspect the generated assembly or machine code and/or measure *very* carefully.  The findings could differ when the executable's deployed on different hardware, compiler with a later version of the compiler, with different flags, a different compiler etc..

Comment: Sorry, both were supposed to be equal, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the two loops are not equivalent:

```
for( int k = 5; k--;) cout << k << endl;
```

prints **4 3 2 1 0**. While

```
for( int k = 5; k > 0; k--) cout << k << endl;
```

prints **5 4 3 2 1**.

In performance point of view, you can have enough confidence in your compiler. Modern compilers know how to optimize this better than we do, in most cases.

Comment: Sorry, both were supposed to be equal, I changed it

Answer (score -1):

It depends on  your compiler.  Probably not, but as always, one must profile to be certain.  Or you could look at the generated assembly code (e.g. `gcc -S`) and see if it's any different.  Make sure to enable optimization before you test, too!